# excel 4.0 macro evaluate

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I am trying to evaluate an equation in Excel where the operation is determined by the value of a cell. For example, let's say I have an equation in `A2` that says `100 (operation) 100`. I want that cell to be evaluated such that `if A1 = 1, then 100*100, if 2 then 100/100, if 3 then 100+100, if 4 then 100-100`. I was able to come up with a solution using `VLOOKUP` to determine the operation, concatenate to combine the numbers with the operation, and Excel 4.0 macro function EVALUATE in a named range to evaluate the text string as a number.

Now, I'd like to do the same thing in VBA (I still have the operation lookup chart, ie `1 = *`, `2 = /`, etc. in Excel sheet). Is there any way to do this without if/then/else statements?

Comment: yup use `worksheets().evaluate("String")` you can load the operands into an array and refer to the array with the value in A1.

Comment: you can also use evaluate in a named formula and bypass VBA...but your work book will need to be saved as an XLSM since EVALUATE is an old VBA builtin function...or something to that effect.

Answer (score 1):

```
Function Eval(eq, op)
    Eval = Application.Evaluate("=" & Replace(eq, "(operation)", Mid("*/+-", op, 1)))
End Function
```

If your equation contains cell references then be sure to use the `Worksheet.Evaluate` form, scoped to the correct worksheet...

Answer (score 0):

Another approach, using select case:

```
Function Calc(eq As Integer, op As Double) As Double
    Select Case eq
        Case 1: Calc = op * op
        Case 2: Calc = op / op
        Case 3: Calc = op + op
        Case 4: Calc = op - op
        Case Else: Calc = 0
    End Select
End Function
```